# Why does my sed search not find alpha in field?

Tags: sed

I want to know why the search criteria in myfile.sed won't filter. I want to filter any alpha within the first column only. That is I want to filter any alpha after the start of line, followed by a `"` chracter and ending with a `"` character and a `,` character, but I am getting data in subsequent columns:

I am using

`sed -f myfile.sed in-file`

The contents of myfile.sed looks like

```
{
        /^"[0-9]+[^0-9]+[0-9]*",/p
        /^"[0-9]+",""/p
}
```

The first few fields of in-file containing the data I want to filter

`"1866TL","1866TL","ME","SUBA","GRY","B","25","40","LAKEHILL AVE"`

I'm interested in printing the line above, because a non-numeric -- TL -- appears in the first column.

To make this work, I have tried substituting the `"` character with `[^0-9A-Za-z]`.

I have tried just searching for a few numbers followed by one character, but cannot make this work.

What am I doing wrong?

After correcting myfile.sed to look like this from @choroba 's answer:

```
{
        /^"[0-9]\+[^0-9]\+[0-9]*",/p
        /^"[0-9]\+",""/p
}
```

I'm getting other fields I did not intend to get.
How do I cut off the search after the comma?

```
"940915","L33677","MA","CHEV","RED","R","25","54","GROVE ST",
"1866TL","1866TL","ME","SUBA","GRY","B","25","40","LAKEHILL AVE",
"966011","1942758","NH","AUDI","BLU","","25","13","MT. VERNON ST.",
```

Comment: Instead of focusing on what you're NOT looking for (digits or other non-alphabetic characters), always try to write your text-processing scripts based on what you ARE looking for (alphabetic characters) and the end result will almost always be clearer, simpler, and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plus must be backslashed to have the special meaning:

```
/^"[0-9]\+[^0-9]\+[0-9]*",/p
```

If you do not want the negated character class to match commas and double quotes, include them:

```
/^"[0-9]\+[^0-9",]\+[0-9]*",/p
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting too much, but at least the line I wanted. I've edited the OP and re-asked the question.

Comment: I've updated the OP to be clearer. Basically, I want to print only if there's an alpha anywhere before the first comma (,) character. Tried your example, and it still gets all lines.

Comment: This answer fixed the use of + in the original script.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Do you run it with `sed -n`? Otherwise, `sed` will always print, even if it does not match anything.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot the -n and that fixes it.

Comment: Would you be willing to comment or edit your answer as to why the negated character class would match commas and double quotes without `/^"[0-9]\+[^0-9",]\+[0-9]*",/p` . I finally get it.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus: Well, comma and double quotes are not `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

sed is an excellent tool for simple subsitutions on a single line, for anything else just use awk:

```
$ cat file
"940915","L33677","MA","CHEV","RED","R","25","54","GROVE ST",
"1866TL","1866TL","ME","SUBA","GRY","B","25","40","LAKEHILL AVE",
"966011","1942758","NH","AUDI","BLU","","25","13","MT. VERNON ST.",

$ awk -F, '$1 ~ /[[:alpha:]]/' file
"1866TL","1866TL","ME","SUBA","GRY","B","25","40","LAKEHILL AVE",
```

Couldn't be much simpler, right?

FWIW here's the sed equivalent:

```
$ sed -n '/^[^,]*[[:alpha:]]/p' file
"1866TL","1866TL","ME","SUBA","GRY","B","25","40","LAKEHILL AVE",
```