# How do I represent " in string?

Tags: regex, perl

I have example inputs to a program. They are

`"1866TL",` and `"965937","`.

The comma is part of what I am trying to match.

I want to match if there are alpha characters in the inputs.

I am getting the argument from @ARGV.

```
$input_line = $ARGV[0];

if ($input_line =~ m/\A\"\d+\D+\d*\",/)
{
    print "Bad match\n";
}
else
{
    print "Good match\n";
}
```

If I substitute `.` for `\"`, I get what I expect, `Bad Match` for the first example that contains `TL`, but not if I put literal quotes `\"` in the regular expression.

How do I represent this input properly as a regex?

Am I missing how `=~` works? I am expecting the first value `"1866TL",` to match and for the program to print out `Bad Match`.

Interestingly, if I print out `$input_line`, figure the quotes have been stripped and search this way, I get what I expect.

```
$input_line = $ARGV[0];

print $input_line."\n";


if ($input_line =~ m/\A\d+[^0-9]+\d*/)
{
    print "Bad match\n";
}
else
{
    print "Good match\n";
}
```

So, what is happening? Are quotes stripped by Perl? Am I missing something else?

Comment: I get the same result with `m/\A.\d+\D+\d*.,/`. Please be more specific.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a mix of «"», «“» and «”»?

Comment: Or maybe you are doing `script.pl "a","b"`. In most shells, that's the same as `script.pl a,b`. In `sh`, you should use `script.pl '"a","b"'` to pass `"a","b"`.

Comment: Good point about putting the value inside single quotes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> So, what is happening? Are quotes stripped by Perl? Am I missing something else?

In Perl, the *string literal* `"abc"` (a piece of code) produces the *string* `abc` (a value). If you want to create the string `"abc"`, you need to use `'"abc"'`, `"\"abc\""` or similar.

Something similar is happening in your shell. For example, in `sh` and derivatives, `foo "abc"` pass the string `abc` to program `foo`. If you want to pass `"abc"`, you need to use `foo '"abc"'` or `foo \"abc\"` or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as written works just fine for me. Although there's actually no need to backslash the quotes.

Comment: You're getting Bad Match? I've edited the OP to cover my misunderstanding of `=~`

Comment: @octopusgrabbus yes. Bad match on `"1866TL",`, good match on `"965937","`

Comment: Could not reproduce it with original method in OP (still).

Answer (score 0):

The problem of your regex might be that `\D` matches too much, i.e. it can match double quotes and commas as well. To prevent that, use a more specific class:

```
m/\A"\d+[^0-9",]+\d*",/
```

as already adviced in https://stackoverflow.com/a/17552454/1030675.

Comment: Thanks for your sed answer yesterday. Could I be having problems because the " characters are being stripped? When I print out `$input_line`, it looks like `1866TL,`. Your fix does not work in this case. If I stop looking for the quotes, this works. I'll go edit the OP to reflect this.